# Cannot use instance member 'form_Mesaj1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift

I want to load form_Mesaj1 in the text data, but I get this error in the form_Mesaj1 line. What is the problem?

import Foundation

```
public struct Message {
    var text:String
    let isIncoming:Bool
    let date:Date
}


class MessageViewController: ChatVCWithTableView {
  let form_Mesaj1 = String()
   private let messages = [
        [
            Message(text:"\(form_Mesaj1)", isIncoming:true, date: Date.dateFromCustomString(dateString: "12/22/2018"))
        ]
```

Comment: It's like the error message say, you can't use form_Mesaj1 in this scope. Initialize `messages` in an `init()` instead (Or use an empty string instead since that is what form_Mesaj1 is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler con not be sure that `form_Mesaj1` is going to initialize before `messages`. It can be sure of that only *after* `self` (all stored properties) has been initialized.

## Lazy way:

So you can make it `lazy`:

```
private lazy var messages =  [
    Message(text:"\(form_Mesaj1)", isIncoming: true, date: Date.dateFromCustomString(dateString: "12/22/2018"))
]
```

This way the compiler can be sure that the `form_Mesaj1` is initialized before using it, because you must call `messages` on an existing ('aka' initialized) object, right?!

---

## More stricted way:

Also up can initialize them manually:

```
class MessageViewController: ChatVCWithTableView {
    let form_Mesaj1: String
    private let messages: [Message]

    init(form_Mesaj1: String) {
        self.form_Mesaj1 = form_Mesaj1
        messages = [
            Message(text:"\(form_Mesaj1)", isIncoming: true, date: Date.dateFromCustomString(dateString: "12/22/2018"))
        ]
    }
}
```